# VBA: copy paste from selected workbooks based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy data from selected different workbooks based on cell value and paste it to one single workbook

```
enter code here
Sub Ram_copypaste()
Dim w As Workbook
Dim A As String
Dim x As Worksheet
Dim j As Integer
Dim i As Integer
j = cells(2, 1).Value
A = "Portfolio"
B = ".xlsx"
For i = 1 To j
Set w = A & i & B
Set x = A & i
w.Worksheets("Download1").Range("A1:H14").Copy
Workbooks("TE copypaste.xlsx").x.cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Set x = A & i, will throw Compile error: Type mismatch, this can be tried yourself.

Comment: Also you haven't declared `B` anywhere

Answer (score 1):

Anil called it, you're declaring x as a worksheet

```
Dim x As Worksheet
```

but you're trying to set it equal to a string

```
A = "Portfolio"
For i = 1
Set x = A & i
```

You're also doing the same thing with W except as a workbook

Maybe try something like

```
set w = Workbooks.Open(<path>\<filename>)
set x = w.sheets(A & I)
```

If the value in cells(2,1) is non numeric you'll get a type mismatch error.

This piece at the top will give you some issues

```
enter code here
```

This might be more suited to what you mentioned in your comment:

```
Sub test()

Dim workBookPath As String, filename As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim awb As Workbook, w As Workbook
Dim x As Worksheet

Set awb = ActiveWorkbook

workBookPath = "C:\users\mt390d\Documents\Reports\"
    If IsNumeric(Cells(2, 1)) Then
        j = Cells(2, 1).Value
        Else: MsgBox ("Cell A2 must contain a number")
        Exit Sub
    End If

For i = 1 To j
    filename = Dir(workBookPath)
    If filename <> awb.Name Then
        Set w = Workbooks.Open(workBookPath & filename)
        Sheets("Download1").Copy awb.Sheets(1)
        Set x = ActiveSheet
        On Error Resume Next
            x.Name = "Portfolio" & i
        On Error GoTo 0
        w.Close
    End If
    filename = Dir()
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting Type mismatch error at Set w = A & i & B

Comment: True - the issue isn't that B was undeclared.  Basically a string is just how the compiler sees text, while a workbook is actually an object, like a box containing properties, values, etc.

Comment: My complete requirement would be:

Comment: here's what that looks like to the compiler: Workbooks("TE copypaste.xlsx").Sheets("Portfolio1").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(8, 14)) = Workbooks("Portfolio1.xlsx").Worksheets("Download1").Range("A1:H14")

Comment: 1) Add multiple sheets to the current workbook based on cell value Ex: cell value is 2 then add 2 sheets. 2) open workbooks from a folder based on the same cell value Ex: if cell value is 2 then open 2 workbooks 3) copy data from opened workbooks to current workbook. in this case from 2 different workbooks to current workbook but in 2 different sheets. I am failing to create a loop at the 3rd step. Please help me.

Comment: It might also help to put that comment into your original question to clarify your intent.  Someone might have a more efficient way of doing that.  HTH :)

Comment: Hi, the code is perfect.. But it has one error.. It is copying from same workbook and pasting to different sheets.. Could you please check this?

Comment: Sure, the workbook path line should be changed to match the path of the files where you would like to retrieve the data into your activesheet.  thinking I might append the second for loop to just drop the data from the array in a single api call too... do you have two separate paths? or should there be a logical comparison based on current workbook name.?

Comment: try this - I've added an object wrapper for your active workbook where the script should be initiated in the event that your data files contain a worksheet named similar to x.  Ensure that your workBookPath string points to the folder where your data files holding your data are located, in this instance the source files are located in "c:\Documents\Reports\"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Use Debug.Print at various points to understand your code better.

```
Sub Ram_copypaste()
Dim w As Workbook
Dim A As String, B As String
Dim x As Worksheet
Dim j As Integer
Dim i As Integer

j = cells(2, 1).Value   'Use Debug.Print to check the value of J
A = "Portfolio"
B = ".xlsx"
For i = 1 To j
Set w = workbooks(A & i & B)   'Make sure you already have a workbook 
   'with the same name as A & i & B opened otherwise this will give error. If 
   'you don't have it opened but have it on your drive first open it and then set it.

set x = w.sheets(A & i)      'As suggested by Anil Kumar to avoid Type Mismatch error
w.Worksheets("Download1").Range("A1:H14").Copy
Workbooks("TE copypaste.xlsx").x.cells(1, 1).Select
Workbooks("TE copypaste.xlsx").x.cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: It is throwing up mismatch @Set w = A & i &

Comment: Yes because I think that's a completely new name of the workbook and you haven't created or opened any workbook that has similar name so it can't be set.